# Download apps from Play Store to a designated folder on desktop

Tags: applications, google-play-store, launcher, home-screen, home-screen-folders

I am running Android 12 on a Realme 8 5G phone. I would like to test a set of note-taking apps. In order to do this, I need to search and download them from Google Play. However, they will be hard to find because they will be arranged alphabetically by app name and I have a lot of apps on my desktop.

So, I would like to be able to create a folder, set the folder and the download location, and then go and download the apps from the Google Play app (so that these go to the set folder).

Is it possible to do this? Do I need a special launcher app on Android to do this?

Comment: Just to avoid misunderstanding: 1. You can not download apps from Google Play Store, you can only install them and Play Store & Services will then download the app file(s) in background and automatically install them. 2. the app icon on your "desktop" is just an icon linked to the app, but never the app itself.  So you can not download anything to your "desktop" - Android is not Windows, it doesn't has an Desktop folder.

Comment: What you want may be possible if there would be a launcher that would allow to add app icons of newly installed apps automatically to a specific location/folder. But I don't know such an app launcher.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't possible to do this in the order you specify, but you can end up with the same result.

## Preparations

You'll have to install the aps you want from the Play Store. That's inescapable. Once you've done that, then you need to organise them into folders.

## Put icons onto home screen

Swipe up on the home screen to get to the list of installed apps. Find one of the apps you want to put into a folder, which I'll call App-A. Tap and hold it and when a menu comes up, tap "Add to Home."

Do the same for another of the apps, which I'll call App-B

## Create the folder

On the home screen, tap and hold App-A and drag it onto App-B. Android creates a folder with the two app icons in it.

It then shows you the folder, with the name "Folder Name" displayed above it. Tap on "Folder Name" and you'll be able to edit it to the name you want.

Tap the "Back" control to get back to the home screen.

## Open the folder

Just tap on it. One it is open, you can interact with the apps on it as if they were on the home screen. Tap the "Back" control to get back to the home screen.

## Add more apps to the folder

Put them onto the home screen, then drag them into the folder.

## Removing apps from the folder

Open the folder, and then drag apps out of it. They move to the home screen.

When you remove the last-but-one app, the folder is removed and the app left in it re-appears on the home screen.